# Apply content to wordpress theme sections

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Somebody help!  I am new to Wordpress and trying to build single page responsive(bootstrap) theme from scratch. My index.php page looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="plx_mission_section" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h2>title</h2></div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><p>text</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="plx_whyus_section" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h2>title</h2></div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><p>text</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

......
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So my question is: How Can I add content to specific section? looked for the answer but could not find good working example.

Comment: If you want to separate your post by author, category or tag, you have to use WP_Query. Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) Loop in each of your sections

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h2>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</h2></div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</h2></div>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Edit $args as needed

Updated:
If it's fixed content in each section I would simply create a new wordpress page for each section. Then you can [run a loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) like this in your index.php

```
<?php

$mypages = get_pages( array( 'include' => '1, 2, 3, 4', 'sort_column' => 'post_title', 'sort_order' => 'asc' ) );

    foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
        $content = $page->post_content;
        if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
            continue;

        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    ?>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2></div>
         <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    <?php
    }   
?>
```

Replace '1, 2, 3, 4' with your new page ids created above.

Comment: Thank you guys..just found this article [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-wp_query-an-introduction--cms-23023) which says that WP_Query itself is more powerful and lets you query almost anything held in your database.So now I am confused ;(

Comment: It doesn't look like you're trying to do anything that complicated so don't overthink it here. What content to you want in each section? Do you want certain post types? Certain categories of posts?

Comment: I have 5 sections:1.MISSION 2.WHY US 3.PORTFOLIO 4.TEAM 5.CONTACT...each has similliar structure:title,content and the portfolio and team members section has image slider plugin.that's it

Comment: Not sure if you would see them but see my update above. There are lots of ways to add portfolios and sliders to each page then use something like the new snippet above to display each page content in a single template.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm happy to; if you could mark this as correct or up vote I appreciate the points